# GET and CONNECT methods in a proxy

Tags: c++, sockets, proxy, http-proxy

I'm making an HTTP proxy in C++; when a client sends a `GET` or `CONNECT` request to the proxy, the proxy parses the HTTP header of the packet, resolve the hostname in it, opens another socket to the server destination and send client's request. Then the proxy will send server's response to the client.

Here's the `GET` and `CONNECT` requests from the client sent by the proxy to the server:

```
GET http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204 HTTP/1.1

CONNECT cr-input.getspeakit.com:443 HTTP/1.1
```

But when I parse a `GET` response from server, I find a 400 status code, i.e. `Bad Request`: this seems to be (from Wikipedia):

> a malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing.

Do I send wrong arguments to the server in the `GET` request?

Comment: Can you include what your proxy is sending to the server?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. GET. The syntax is not wrong but if the request has not been faked by you and it is really going to www.gstatic.com you can check yourself that any kind of requests generates a 40x status code. That's a domain used for Google for offloading static content. Whether that's still the case and why it returns 40x for the requests. Go to Google.
2. CONNECT. If you are forwarding the CONNECT to the server, this is wrong. A CONNECT is meant to open an end to end binary connection bypassing your proxy. The sequence would be:

   - Get connect request from client
   - Open TCP connection to IP:Port (after DNS resolution obviously)
   - Return "200 OK" to the client if the connection was successfully opened or an error code of your choice (plus optionally some explanation in Text/HTML form for the end user)
   - If data is received from either end -> forward it to the other end until one of the connections is closed, when you close the other end.

Comment: He should remove the hostname and port part of the GET request. That's only for proxies.

Comment: There is no port in the GET request and specifiying the full URL is HTTP 1.1. From RFC 2616 an example of a Request URI: `GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1`

Comment: So if I get `CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.youtube.com:443
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36

`, the TCP connection I must open is SSLed because of 443 port?

Comment: Your proxy must in simply open the binary connections to the parties and connect them (by means of moving packets back and forth). The SSL connection (if it is one) will be open by the parties at the ends and not by the proxy. It is of course possible to intercept the connection (MITM) like for example Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) does to allow you to debug things.